# Alter values of dictionaries which have the same keys in a list

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I had this:

`[{'name': 'Peter'}, {'name': 'Anna'}]`

And I wanted to make this out of it:

`[{'name': 'Peter Williams'}, {'name': 'Anna Williams'}]`

So I did:

```
>>> li = [{'name': 'Peter'}, {'name': 'Anna'}]
>>> new_li = []
>>> dic = {}
>>> for i in li:
...     dic["name"] = i["name"] + " Williams"
...     new_li.append(dic)
```

But:

```
>>> new_li
[{'name': 'Anna Williams'}, {'name': 'Anna Williams'}]
```

Why?

Could you also show how to best get `[{'name': 'Peter Williams'}, {'name': 'Anna Williams'}]`?

**Edit**

The reason why I didn't understand this behavior is because I assumed that:

```
>>> dict = {'name':'Peter'}
>>> lis = [dict]
>>> dict['name'] = 'Olaf'
```

Where

```
>>> print lis
```

gives

```
[{'name': 'Peter'}]
```

While it actually is

```
[{'name': 'Olaf'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the same dictionary object in each iteration.

On the second iteration, you are altering the value that you assigned to the `name` key in the previous iteration, and your list ends up containing two references to the same object.

I'd strongly recommend checking out the "Python Tutor" tool (pythontutor.com), which allows you to visualise the execution of some python code, and see what objects are being created in the stack. e.g. [Python Tutor with your code](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=li+=+%5B%7B%27name%27%3a+%27Peter%27%7D,+%7B%27name%27%3a+%27Anna%27%7D%5D%0Anew_li+=+%5B%5D%0Adic+=+%7B%7D%0Afor+i+in+li%3a%0A++++dic%5B%22name%22%5D+=+i%5B%22name%22%5D+++%22+Williams%22%0A++++new_li.append%28dic%29&mode=display&cumulative=false&py=2&curInstr=10)

The correct way to do what you wanted would be:

```
li = [{'name': 'Peter'}, {'name': 'Anna'}]
new_li = []
for p in li:
    new_p = {'name': p['name'] + ' Williams'}
    new_li.append(new_p)
```

This way a new dictionary object is created with each iteration.

**A more concise solution:**

```
li = [{'name': 'Peter'}, {'name': 'Anna'}]
new_li = [{'name': p['name'] + ' Williams'} for p in li]
```

Comment: Thank you for also mentioning Python tutor!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new dictionary on each iteration of the loop, otherwise on each iteration you modify and append the same object to `new_li`:

```
>>> li = [{'name': 'Peter'}, {'name': 'Anna'}]
>>> new_li = []
>>> for i in li:
...     new_li.append({'name': i['name'] + ' Williams'})
...
>>> new_li
[{'name': 'Peter Williams'}, {'name': 'Anna Williams'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to alter it in-place. You don't need to make a new dict.

```
for d in inlist:
    d["name"] += " Williams"
```

Is all you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have run into a really nasty problem. The problem is with your `dic`. You are iterating over the list of names, and first you hit the one with 'Peter'. At this point, you set `dic` to `{'name': 'Peter Williams'}` and append it. But then, you hit the one with 'Anna' and change that very same `dic` to `{'name': 'Anna Williams'}`. So you end up with the *same* dictionary in your list *twice*. To fix this, you will need to do this instead:

```
new_li = []
for i in li:
      n_li.append({'name': i['name'] + ' Williams'})
```